# Infinite Cartesian Product, Metric Triangle Inequality

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, compactness

For $\{X_j : j\in \mathbb{Z}^+\},$ each compact metric spaces, the infinite Cartesian product metric space is defined as
$$X = \prod_{j=1}^{\infty} X_j$$

We make X a metric space by setting
$$d(x,y) = \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} 2^{-j} \frac{d_j(p_j(x),p_j(y))}{1+d_j(p_j(x),p_j(y))}$$

where $p_j(x) = x_j$, the j'th component of x, and $d_j$ is just the standard distance function for the corresponding component in x and y.

I am trying to demonstrate that the triangle inequality holds here, namely that
$$d(x,y) \leq d(x,z) + d(y,z)$$

I'm given the hint to note that $\phi(r) = \frac{r}{1+r}$, but I'm unsure of how to put it to use.

Comment: Note that $x\mapsto \frac x{1+x}$ is a concave function $[0,\infty)$ and therefore is subadditive, and is also bounded above by $1$.

Comment: My understanding of subadditivity is not strong enough to use that for my proof. We have learned it in my class yet, so there's probably a more fundamental way for me to show it

Comment: Subadditivity would yield that $\frac{d_j}{1+d_j}$ is a metric on $X_j$.

Comment: I figured it out! Thanks.